# Reduce or eliminate persistent connections mysql

Tags: mysql

I am trying to fine tune mysql on a VPS of 2G Ram Linux Centos, I used mysqltuner.pl the report says:

```
    General recommendations:     
    Add skip-innodb to MySQL configuration to disable InnoDB     
    MySQL started within last 24 hours - recommendations may be inaccurate     
    Enable the slow query log to troubleshoot bad queries     
    **Reduce or eliminate persistent connections to reduce connection usage**     
    When making adjustments, make tmp_table_size/max_heap_table_size equal     
    Reduce your SELECT DISTINCT queries without LIMIT clauses 

Variables to adjust:    
max_connections (> 151)     
wait_timeout (< 28800)    
interactive_timeout (< 28800)     
tmp_table_size (> 16M)     
max_heap_table_size (> 16M)
```

I have a question regarding "Reduce or eliminate persistent connections to reduce connection usage":
1. How do I know how many connections are there when my site is running-written in PHP?
2. How to reduce them or eliminate them? If there a variable in my.cnf setting targeted for that or I have to do it on the PHP side?

Pls help, as I am still do trials and erros, I am learning but still not so knowledgable about mysql. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Just don't use persistent connections in your PHP application (most likely you aren't using them, since setting them up requires using special functions/flags, so you would know that).

See manual entry for [`mysql_pconnect`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-pconnect.php) (also note links there to mysqli and PDO)